# c# console dice roll

Tags: c#, console

I am having problems with a program. I need to compare the number of combinations, if they are the same, the higher value wins. Else if the number of combinations are the same and the value are the same, it is a tie. here what I have so far.

```
        int[] player1 = new int[6];
        int[] player2 = new int[6];

        Random rndGen = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int diceRoll = 0;

            diceRoll = rndGen.Next(6);
            player1[diceRoll]++;
            Console.WriteLine("Computer rolled: {0}", diceRoll + 1);

        }//end for

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int diceRoll = 0;
            diceRoll = rndGen.Next(6);
            player2[diceRoll]++;
            Console.WriteLine("You rolled: {0}", diceRoll + 1);

        }//end for

        int maxPlayer1 = 0, maxPlayer2 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (player1[i] > player1[maxPlayer1]) maxPlayer1 = i;
            if (player2[i] > player2[maxPlayer2]) maxPlayer2 = i;
        }//end for

        if (player1[maxPlayer1] > player2[maxPlayer2])
            Console.WriteLine("Computer won with {0} of a kind", player1[maxPlayer1], maxPlayer1 + 1);
        else
            if (player2[maxPlayer2] > player1[maxPlayer1])
                Console.WriteLine("You won with {0} of a kind", player2[maxPlayer2], maxPlayer2 + 1);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Tie");

    }//end main
}
```

}

Comment: What problems are you actually having? Does it compile? What errors does it give? What output do you get?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.  What do you expect the output to be? Can you give an example of dice rolls and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Is `player1[diceRoll]++` really what you mean to do?

Comment: It looks like they're trying to track how many times each value is rolled, so it's probably intentional.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, here are some things you should check:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

This loop will execute 4 times, where i = 1, 2, 3, 4. That's almost certainly not what you were trying to do.

Arrays are zero-indexed. That means that the first value is at index 0, the second at index 1, etc. For an array of length 6, the last value will be at index 5.

When using formatted strings, the first parameter is the format and then every other parameter is referred to with a number, starting at 0. So for this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("You won with {0} of a kind", player2[maxPlayer2], maxPlayer2 + 1);
```

the parameter `maxPlayer2 + 1` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bug at the third for-loop:

```
 int maxPlayer1 = 0, maxPlayer2 = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
 {
    if (player1[i] > player1[maxPlayer1]) maxPlayer1 = i;
    if (player2[i] > player2[maxPlayer2]) maxPlayer2 = i;
 }//end for
```

It should be:

```
 int maxPlayer1 = 0, maxPlayer2 = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
    if (player1[i] > player1[maxPlayer1]) maxPlayer1 = i;
    if (player2[i] > player2[maxPlayer2]) maxPlayer2 = i;
 }//end for
```

Comment: Yea I noticed that as well. plus my logic is wrong. Not always right.